# pass what ever I type into another div using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Every time I type something in the input box and I click submit I only want to place that text into a div. Thanks in advance

```
<div class="row" >
     <form>
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10 ">
              <input type="text">
         </div>

         <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2 center form-button" >
              <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-orange" >
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-offset-2 " id="up" ><br/>
              <span class="label label-primary" >Whatever i type have to go here</span>
         </div>
     </form>
</div>`
```

Comment: why dont to show your HTML ?

Comment: I try this on angular but it does not work since is submitting the entire form. so i decide to do this on Jquery

Comment: sorry Vivekh. I just did

Comment: using jquery you can use .keyup

Comment: thanks guys all you suggestion works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you something like this

```
<script>
    $('.btn').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.label-primary').text($('input[type="text"]').val());
    });
</script>
```

Comment: that works good. How about adding each word next to the other one every time I click add?

Comment: var existing_val = $('.label-primary').text();
        $('.label-primary').text(existing_val + ' ' + $('input[type="text"]').val());

Answer (score 0):

http://fiddle.jshell.net/ZXWgN/

html

```
<div class="row" >
         <form>
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10 ">
              <input type="text">
         </div>

         <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2 center form-button" >
          <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-orange" >
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-offset-2 " id="up" ><br/>
              <span class="label label-primary" >Whatever i type have to go here</span>
     </div>
     </form>
</div>`
```

java script

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var msg = $('input[type="text"]').val();
   $('#up').find('span').text(msg);
});
```

Comment: that works good. How about adding each word next to the other one every time I click add?

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".btn btn-orange").click(function(){

```
       $(".label label-primary").text($('input[type="text"]').value());
```

});
});